# Sharepoint 2013 double encoding issue

Tags: sharepoint-server

Sharepoint 2013 has double encoding issues where spaces in URL show up as %2520. I understand what this means.  = %20 on first encode, then <%> = %25 on second encode, so I end up with %2520. I do not know how to stop the double encoding from occurring. This was not upgraded from another previous edition or migrated, this event just randomly started around two weeks ago. Do you guys have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old bug, from a 2014 Cumulative Update if I recall. Install a newer CU, such as the March or April 2016 which appear to be fairly stable.

EDIT: It was from April 2014/MS14-022: https://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/06/workaround-ms14-022-double-encoding-bug/. Resolved with the September 2014 CU.

Comment: I looked in the search.clientControls.js files for the encodeURI rules but I was unable to locate them in the exact context they were written in the link above. I appreciate your help and fast response.

Comment: What patch level are you at?

Comment: 15.0.4797.1000 is the version in settings

Comment: Are you installing just Security hotfixes or CUs? That is the Feb 2016 round of patches, but it could be simply security patches.

Comment: CUs havent been done in some time, but just standard updates. I had one set that kept failing and it seemed to be due to the OWSTIMER. That is the only thing they shared in common. Do you have a link to a good new release of the most current CU and do you think this would fix the issue?

Comment: I would install the [April 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114938) or [March 2016 CU](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114827).

Comment: If i have standard will the April 2016 work? It says for Sharepoint Enterprise Server 2013

Comment: Yes. You can technically even install the Project Server CU on SharePoint Standard/Enterprise -- it only updates the bits that are present in the product.

Comment: @TrevorSeward - Hey Trevor - have you come across any issues with the April 2016 CU on SharePoint Server 2013? I'm preparing to patch one farm and not really seeing anything online. Just wanted to double check before I install :-). Thanks for any feedback!